# ValueError: Invalid broadcasting comparison with block values - pandas in pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, array-broadcasting

Hi I have two data frames and trying to compare the values in it but facing a ValueError in broadcasting:

```
    dict_1 = {'a': {0: [{'value': 'A123',
    'label': 'Professional'},
   {'value': 'B141', 'label': 'Passion'}]},
 'b': {0: [{'value': 'B5529',
    'label': 'Innovation'},
   {'value': 'B3134', 'label': 'Businees Value'},
   {'value': 'B3856',
    'label': 'Electrofication'},
   {'value': 'B3859', 'label': 'Insurance'},
   {'value': 'B3856', 'label': 'Requirements'},
   {'value': 'B3345', 'label': 'Stories'}]},
    "c" : "hello"}
    
    dict_2 = {'a': {0: np.nan},
 'b': {0: [{'value': 'B4785',
    'label': 'Innovation'},
   {'value': 'B4635', 'label': 'Businees Value'},
   {'value': 'B1234', 'label': 'Requirements'},
   {'value': 'B9853', 'label': 'Stories'}]},
          'c': "hello"
         }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)
```

Here I wanted to compare two rows only but not two complete dataframes (as I had a scenario that `shape of df1=(500, 2)` and shape of `shape of df2 = (1, 2)`). So I used the below code two extract the different values in the rows .

```
df1[~(df1[['a', 'b', 'c']] == df2[['a', 'b', 'c']].iloc[0])]
```

The desired result should be:

[image]

Here, `df2` which has one row should compare with every row values of `df1`(in my scenario I have more than 1 row). If they are identical then it should be `nan` else I should get the corresponding values of df1

Comment: what's the source? you need to create a tabular model before doing any comparisons

Comment: @Manakin df2 has only one row only in my scenario and wanted to compare with every row of df1

Comment: @Mankin Sorry Now I had updated the question clearly. Thanks in advance